# Typescript compiler, or ES2015 - do either optimize code?

Tags: typescript, optimization, ecmascript-6

In compiler land for other languages something like this would be optimized when it's compiled to be pulled out of the loop so a new object isn't created each time:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr.map(num => {

    const one_time = 5; // this never changes, can be lifted out of the loop.

    return num * one_time;
 })
```

I tried to see if the typescript compiler changes the above code but it doesn't seem to - maybe something else takes care of it? Or maybe the object creation will assign that variable and never change it.

I don't expect ES2015 to do it since it's interpreted but I'm happy to be wrong.

Bonus points if anyone can tell me how to best figure this out for myself in the future.

Thanks guys!

Comment: In any optimising compiler I know, in this example the constant would inlined into the multiplication expression, not the variable declaration be hoisted out of the loop :-)

Comment: "*I don't expect ES2015 to do it since it's interpreted*" - what makes you think that JS is interpreted? All contemporary engines use a JIT optimising compiler. (Which for your example probably would figure out that for a loop over 5 items, any optimisation would be more costly than just interpreting it).

Comment: Totally fair Bergi, in this case I wasn’t trying to illustrate the constant length array, but that means I gave a bad example! Very good point!

Comment: I also didn’t realize that any code was optimized with interpreters, and I didn’t realize there was any sort of engine used. Could you point me to some resources? I’m interested in learning about it

Comment: For a first overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine. Many of these have some engineering blogs where they talk about the optimisations implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the TypeScript compiler doesn't do any optimizations. That's one of its non-goals:

> **Non-goals**
>
> - Aggressively optimize the runtime performance of programs. Instead, emit idiomatic JavaScript code that plays well with the performance characteristics of runtime platforms.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals

As for ES2015, that's a language specification. JS engines will compile and optimize though.

Comment: Thanks David! Great answer, I see why they do that. However, the first sentence of the quote confuses things a bit but I get the intention. Maybe remove it?

Comment: I provided a bit more context to the quote. I see how that was confusing.